# Android- Stackoverflowerror in navigation in master-detail flow

Tags: android, android-fragments

We have a master-detail flow, and both the master and the detail fragments are 'added' via the fragment manager with backstack as shown below,

we add master fragment from homefragment as,

```
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, <masterfragment>, "master")
                    .addToBackStack()
                    .commit();
```

and from master we do the same way to add the child fragment, when user click on a row,

```
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, <detailfragment>, "detail")
                    .addToBackStack()
                    .commit();
```

Now we get a random stackoverflowerror, after the user navigates back and forth between master and detail fragment for more than 100 times,

```
 android.support.v4.app.Fragment.c  

    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.a    

    android.support.v4.app.Fragment.c   

    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.a    

    android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onPreparePanel  

    android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onPreparePanel   

    android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase$AppCompatWindowCallbackBase.onPreparePanel

   android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onPreparePanel    

    android.support.v7.internal.app.ToolbarActionBar$ToolbarCallbackWrapper.onPreparePanel

    android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onPreparePanel   

    android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase$AppCompatWindowCallbackBase.onPreparePanel

android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onPreparePanel   

  android.support.v7.internal.app.ToolbarActionBar$ToolbarCallbackWrapper.onPreparePanel
```

After a few hours of analysis, we found that every time we set the support actionbar with the toolbar in our fragment, (both master and detail fragment has different toolbars)

```
getActivity().setSupportActionBar(mToolBar);
```

a new ToolbarActionBar object is created, and the window callback is set with a **new wrappedwindow callback**, (the following snippet is copied from android source from class, AppCompatDelegateImplV7)

```
 ToolbarActionBar tbab = new ToolbarActionBar(toolbar, ((Activity) mContext).getTitle(),
            mWindow);
    setSupportActionBar(tbab);
    mWindow.setCallback(tbab.getWrappedWindowCallback());
```

a new ToolbarCallbackWrapper is created in ToolbarActionBar class, (the following snippet is copied from android source), as in the source below, the new callback wrapper is created again from the previous window callback.

```
 public ToolbarActionBar(Toolbar toolbar, CharSequence title, Window window) {
        mDecorToolbar = new ToolbarWidgetWrapper(toolbar, false);
        mWindowCallback = new ToolbarCallbackWrapper(window.getCallback());
        mDecorToolbar.setWindowCallback(mWindowCallback);
        toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(mMenuClicker);
        mDecorToolbar.setWindowTitle(title);

        mWindow = window;
    }
```

and so for every call to set support actionbar, it creates a nested object of toolbarcallbackwrapper class, as shown in the below debug 'object trace'

```
this = {ToolbarActionBar$ToolbarCallbackWrapper@5428} 
 this$0 = {ToolbarActionBar@5429} 
 mWrapped = {ToolbarActionBar$ToolbarCallbackWrapper@5423} 
  this$0 = {ToolbarActionBar@5424} 
  mWrapped = {ToolbarActionBar$ToolbarCallbackWrapper@5417} 
   this$0 = {ToolbarActionBar@5418} 
   mWrapped = {ToolbarActionBar$ToolbarCallbackWrapper@5412} 
    this$0 = {ToolbarActionBar@5413} 
    mWrapped = {ToolbarActionBar$ToolbarCallbackWrapper@5382} 
     this$0 = {ToolbarActionBar@5383} 
     mWrapped = {ToolbarActionBar$ToolbarCallbackWrapper@5309} 
      this$0 = {ToolbarActionBar@5310} 
      mWrapped = {ToolbarActionBar$ToolbarCallbackWrapper@5196} 
       this$0 = {ToolbarActionBar@5198} 
       mWrapped = {AppCompatDelegateImplV14$AppCompatWindowCallbackV14@5443}
```

so whenever toolbar is 'prepared' for a fragment, the callback is being called again and again resulting in stackoverflow error, (because after around 100+ navigations, the nested objects depth has gone beyond 100).

How do we solve this?